# XEN виртуализация и ОЗУ

Tags: xen

Доброго времени суток. Решил тут поиграться с VPS на базе XEN, т.к. OpenVZ растраивает. Взял триалку на 363 Мб. Потребление памяти было большое, посему прописал в rc "ulimit -s 1024". После перезагрузки оно заметно упало. Проставил туда lamp-у. Доставил nginx, php-apc. Залил тестовый сайт и пощёлкал по страницам. Потребление ОЗУ - 290 Мб. Т.е. с резервом в 70.

Мои клиенты не хотят платить много за VPS, а посему максимум, что я могу им предложить - стандартный бомж-пакет на 256 Мб. Но как люди укладываются в 256? Или они бьются о потолок, т.е. swap, как только на сайт заходит больше 1 человека? Какой смысл тогда брать VPS, стоимостью в 10 обычных хостингов, если оно будет тормозить похлеще этих самых хостингов-общаг?

Я догадываюсь, что можно подшаманить над MySQL, и сэкономить ещё 30-60 Мб, но в итоге всё равно будет 230 Мб. Какие ещё шаманские танцы нужны?

P.S. я ни разу не админ... :)

Comment: Загляни, может что-нибудь интересное увидишь по оптимизацииhttp://manualpages.pro/node/31http://habrahabr.ru/post/56497/

Answer (score 1):

> /etc/my.cnf skip-innodb.

Метров 100 должно высвободиться.